# How to active a button only when a file uploaded and checked terms and conditions?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a page which have to upload a list of people and agree to the terms and conditions before click on pay button. How to disable a button till they upload the file and checked into the terms and conditions checkbox?

```
    //fileuploadFunction (Convert to json)
    $(document).ready(function(){
          $("#employeelist").change(function(evt){
             window.selectedFile = evt.target.files[0];
             convertToExcel(); return false;
          });
    });
```

```html
    <!--File-->
    <input type="file" id="employeelist" name="employeelist" autofocus autocomplete="off" accept=".csv, .xls, .xlsx" /> 


    <!--CheckBox-->
    <input type="checkbox" name="termsNcon" value="termsNcon" id="termsNcon" /> I have read and agree to the Terms and Conditions and Privacy Policy

    <!--button-->            
    <button id="stripe-button"> >Continue to Pay</button>
```

I need to enable >Continue to Pay button only when a file is uploaded and checked on Terms and Conditions.

Comment: I think you can use html5 `required` https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_required.asp

Comment: Use a promise for that. after that resolve enable the button

Comment: @indefinite Hi, I doesn't work since the button is a stripe simple checkout button.

Comment: @DarshanaPathum can you give me a example with a code? please!

Comment: [Try this](https://api.jquery.com/promise/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#employeelist").change(function(evt){
    window.selectedFile = evt.target.files[0];
    var terms = $('#termsNcon').is(":checked");
    if(window.selectedFile && terms){
      $('#stripe-button').prop("disabled", false);
    } else {
      $('#stripe-button').prop("disabled", true);
    }
    //convertToExcel(); 
    return false;
  });
  
  $('#termsNcon').change(function(){
    var terms = $('#termsNcon').is(":checked");
    if(window.selectedFile && terms){
      $('#stripe-button').prop("disabled", false);
    } else {
      $('#stripe-button').prop("disabled", true);
    }
    //convertToExcel(); 
    return false;
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
//File
<input type="file" id="employeelist" name="employeelist" autofocus autocomplete="off" accept=".csv, .xls, .xlsx" /> 


//CheckBox
<input type="checkbox" name="termsNcon" value="termsNcon" id="termsNcon" /> I have read and agree to the Terms and Conditions and Privacy Policy

//button            
<button id="stripe-button" disabled>Continue to Pay</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).on("change","#ckbx",function(){
if($(this).is(":checked")) {
$("#btn").prop("disabled",false);
}
else{
$("#btn").prop("disabled",true);
}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="ckbx" type="checkbox" />
<input id="btn" type="button" disabled="true" value="submit" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

```js
// find elements
var fileCtrl = $("#employeelist");
var termsCtrl = $("#termsNcon");
var btn = $("#stripe-button");

function checkValidation() {
 if(fileCtrl.val() && termsCtrl.prop("checked")) {
   btn.attr("disabled", false);
  }
  else {
   btn.attr("disabled", true);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" id="employeelist" name="employeelist" autofocus autocomplete="off" accept=".csv, .xls, .xlsx" onchange="checkValidation()" /> 
<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="termsNcon" id="termsNcon" onchange="checkValidation()" /> <label for="termsNcon">I have read and agree to the Terms and Conditions and Privacy Policy</label>
<br />
<button id="stripe-button" disabled>Continue to Pay</button>
```